# Why the VM windows 7 can't access internet?

Tags: networking, vmware

This is the ipv4 configuration in the virtual machine of Windows 7 pro

Ip address: 192.168.100.40
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.100.1

I used static addressing.
The network parameters are correct. Since, This is the configuration of the host
IP address: 192.168.100.33
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.100.1

I just don't understand why the host machine can access internet and the VM can't.

The network adapter configured in VMware workstation is bridge. I am working in VMware workstation 15.5.

Despite the fact I also tried in other networks modes. It keeps without connection. I'd really appreciate any help
Thanks for reading

Comment: Try  Basic TCP/IP Reset:        Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer
Then test

Comment: Another thing to try is to open the VMware Network Editor and restore defaults.  That might also help

Comment: Did you try either (or both) suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

On the VM Open CMD as administrator and run the following commands:

•   Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
```

•   Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

```
netsh int ip reset reset.log
```

•   Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

```
netsh advfirewall reset
```

•   Flush DNS resolver cache:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

•   Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

```
ipconfig /registerdns
```

•   Flush routing table (reboot required):

```
route /f
```

Now reboot your VM and hopefully that will bring back internet.